# Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.brs.BrsbusApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml, spring-annotations, component-scan

earlier my application was working fine but suddenly console is showing this error.

```
2022-11-22 14:21:03.105  INFO 8304 --- [           main] com.brs.BrsbusApplication                : Starting BrsbusApplication using Java 19 on INLEN8520062152 with PID 8304 (C:\Users\sumkukre\Documents\bus reservation system\bus-backend\bus-backend\target\classes started by sumkukre in C:\Users\sumkukre\Documents\bus reservation system\bus-backend\bus-backend)
2022-11-22 14:21:03.121  INFO 8304 --- [           main] com.brs.BrsbusApplication                : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-11-22 14:21:03.772  WARN 8304 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.brs.BrsbusApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration due to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
2022-11-22 14:21:03.787  INFO 8304 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


2022-11-22 14:21:03.819 ERROR 8304 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.brs.BrsbusApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration due to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:609) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:110) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:812) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:192) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.brs.BrsbusApplication.main(BrsbusApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration due to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:51) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:225) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:371) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:271) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:599) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ServletRegistrationBean
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.checkServletRegistrations(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.java:157) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.access$100(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.java:61) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DefaultDispatcherServletCondition.getMatchOutcome(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.java:121) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:45) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 29 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried changing java versions and dependencies but nothing works

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BrsbusApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(BrsbusApplication.class, args);
   }

}
```

Comment: You are clearly mixing incompatible versions. You have stuff from Spring Boot 1.2.1 and Spring Boot 2.7.4 on your classpath. So in short your dependencies are a mess, fix/clean those.